# How to handle onclick null error for HTML added via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `markup` that is added via `JS` that has an `onclick` action (it's a close button).

Essentially:

- User clicks play button
- A modal appears with the video and a close modal button (both which are added via `JS`)

As my close button (`.modal--close`) isn't on the page on load, I'm getting a `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')` (I think).

My thoughts are that the because the `DOMContentLoaded` event was already fired at this point, it is causing the error? But unsure how to resolve it.

#### Demo

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  ready();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
}

function ready() {

  if(document.querySelector(".open-video")){
    document.querySelector(".open-video").onclick = function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var modal = document.querySelector(".videoModal");

      // get data
      var triggerURL  = this.getAttribute("href");
      var triggerID   = this.getAttribute("data-modal");

      // update modal attributes  with trigger data
      modal.setAttribute("data-video", triggerURL);
      modal.setAttribute("id", triggerID);

      var modalID = '#'+ triggerID;
      modal.classList.add("modal--open");

      var html = '<a href="#" class="modal--close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="'+ triggerURL + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';

      modal.innerHTML = html;

      return false;
    }
  }

  // close modal
  document.querySelector(".modal--close").onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
  }

}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 70px 80px;
}
.modal--close {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  top: 32px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
.modal--close:hover:before, .modal--close:hover:after {
  background-color: #F15A40;
}
.modal--close:before, .modal--close:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.modal--close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.modal--close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.modal--open {
  display: block;
}
.modal .modal__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 150;
}
.modal .modal__wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.modal .modal__wrapper iframe, .modal .modal__wrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
.modal .modal__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<a class="button--play open-video" data-modal="video--1" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI">Click me</a>

<div class="videoModal modal modal__post--modal">
  <a id="modal_close" class="modal__close"></a>
  <div class="modal__wrapper"></div>
  <div class="modal__overlay"></div>
</div>
```

#### Edit

Have also tried moving the event listener after the markup has been added:

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  ready();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
}

function ready() {

  let video_btn = document.querySelector(".open-video");
  let close_btn = document.querySelector(".modal--close");
  let modal     = document.querySelector(".videoModal");

  if(video_btn){
    video_btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // get data
      var triggerURL  = this.getAttribute("href");
      var triggerID   = this.getAttribute("data-modal");

      // update modal attributes  with trigger data
      modal.setAttribute("data-video", triggerURL);
      modal.setAttribute("id", triggerID);

      var modalID = '#'+ triggerID;
      modal.classList.add("modal--open");

      var html = '<a href="#" class="modal--close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="'+ triggerURL + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';

      modal.innerHTML = html;

      return false;

      close_btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("test");
      });

    });
  }

}
```

With the above, the `modal` launches fine, but when I click `.modal--close`, nothing happens (no `console.log` and no console errors).

#### Edit 2

Have also tried moving the second event listener above the code snippet that adds the markup:

```js
var html = '<a href="#" class="modal--close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="'+ triggerURL + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';

close_btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("test");
});

modal.innerHTML = html;

return false;
```

With the above however, when I click the `.open-video` button, I get the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

Comment: Move the DOM adding part on top `modal.innerHTML = html;` and afterwards query your document for the elements you added.

Comment: Hi @Supportic - Have just tried this, to no avail. Have updated question to show approach.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  
  ready();

} else {

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

}

function ready() {

  var modal = document.querySelector(".videoModal");

  var triggerURL;


  if(document.querySelector(".open-video")){

    document.querySelector(".open-video").onclick = function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // get data
      triggerURL  = this.getAttribute("href");
  
      var triggerID   = this.getAttribute("data-modal");

      // update modal attributes  with trigger data
      modal.setAttribute("data-video", triggerURL);
  
      modal.setAttribute("id", triggerID);

      var modalID = '#'+ triggerID;
      
      modal.classList.add("modal--open");

      return false;
    }
  }

  // close modal

  var html = '<a href="#" class="modal--close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="'+ triggerURL + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';

  modal.innerHTML = html;

  if(document.querySelector(".modal--close")){

    document.querySelector(".modal--close").onclick = function (e) {
  
        e.preventDefault();
  
        console.log("test");

    }
  }

}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 70px 80px;
}
.modal--close {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  top: 32px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
.modal--close:hover:before, .modal--close:hover:after {
  background-color: #F15A40;
}
.modal--close:before, .modal--close:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.modal--close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.modal--close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.modal--open {
  display: block;
}
.modal .modal__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 150;
}
.modal .modal__wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.modal .modal__wrapper iframe, .modal .modal__wrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
.modal .modal__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<a class="button--play open-video" data-modal="video--1" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI">Click me</a>

<div class="videoModal modal modal__post--modal">
  <a id="modal_close" class="modal__close"></a>
  <div class="modal__wrapper"></div>
  <div class="modal__overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Just wrap the code snippet that fires the issues with below function.

```js
if(document.querySelector(".modal--close")){
}
```

Comment: But would this not check if the element exists on load (the close button doesn't exist on load)? For example, using your demo, the `console.log()` doesn't appear on click - fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vasf37hj/

Comment: Can you be little bit more specific, Freddy?

Comment: Sure :) The fiddle in my comment above is the code you have in your answer. In the code, when the `.modal--close` button is clicked, I want to simply output `console.log("test");`. However, that log isn't appearing in the console, meaning the click event isn't triggering. My second point was, wouldn't adding `if(document.querySelector(".modal--close")){` check for the existence of the element on load, which wouldn't work, because the `.modal--close` element is added via JS, after another button (`.open-video`) is clicked.

Comment: I am sorry for late answer. I let it output `console.log("test")`. Check the code snippets above again. I hope that will work out for you.